# Parse vs. Google Cloud

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, google-cloud-platform

I am a beginner app developer working on a small project. I would like to use Facebook's api to have users login and be able to post information about events.

My question: should I stick to using [Parse](https://parse.com/), or should I consider [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/) as a platform for the app?

I plan on starting with iOS and then Android depending on how the iOS version goes. Let me know your opinions.

Comment: Parse scales pretty well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you specifically note that you're a beginner, my opinion is to push forward with what you know as long as it's technically feasible.

The answer is not solely a technical one, but a lesson most often learned through years of product management. Here it is: **The best technical solution is not always the best business solution.**

The basic point being that if you can get your product developed, delivered to market, and generating revenue faster with the technology (Parse in this case) you already know ... that may be the best way to go. If there is a negligible difference in learning, setting up, using and deploying a custom cloud backend then select the path that sets you up best for further growth. But it is very unlikely that the difference in negligible unless you're already a Google Cloud expert.

Ideas are abundant. Execution is difficult and rare. Execute today so that your idea can live on. As it puts money in your pocket, or fulfills whatever mission you're on, you can make changes as technology and business demands.

Comment: except when parse crashes left and right...